# How much data is transfered during the first http request

Tags: performance, http, tcp

I would like to have a lightning fast website, which is focussed on mobile. Therefore I would like to inline as much graphics, styles and scripts as possible and only use one or two fast HTTP-Requests to display the first part of the page.

My question is how much can I inline, how big may my document get until it gets divided.

As I know so far HTTP uses TCP to send the IP Packets and TCP has a window how far the last send and highest acknowledged Packet may be appart and it scales this window.

But how much payload can be transported, before the server has to wait for an ACK of my client in worst case (first window send, no ACKs received yet). And what does it depend to, the browser, the OS, the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how much payload can be transported, before the server has to wait for an ACK of my client in worst case (first window send, no ACKs received yet). And what does it depend to, the browser, the OS, the device?

It depends on the size of the socket receive buffer in the receiver.

Comment: So e.g. for Android it would be [4097 byte](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_RCVBUF)?

Comment: I have no idea what the default socket receive buffer size on Android is. The link you cite says `4098`, you say `4097`, I would think `4096` more likely than either of them.

Comment: I wanted to say 4098, how comes that you substract 2 Bytes?

Comment: Because buffer sizes are usually a power of 2.